# Sketch the support of random vector

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $n$ balls numbered $1,\dots,n$. $s$ balls are drawn without replacement. Let $X_i$ be a random variable for $ith$ number drawn and 
>   and $X_j$ a random variable for $jth$ number drawn. Support of $X_i$ is $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and support of $X_j$ is $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

I was wondering if it is possible to sketch the support of $(X_i,X_j)$.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Ops, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** What are the only pairs in $\{1, \ldots, n\} \times \{1, \ldots, n\}$ that cannot be represented by $(X_i, X_j)$?  The key words are "without replacement".

Comment: Hi, I know that $X_i \ne X_j$, I was thinking something like http://imgur.com/QpVzyqS

Comment: @Paul: That seems almost right, except that you have the pairs $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$.  Why?